# Access denied when using SyncLock/lock

Tags: c#, vb.net, locking, synclock

This error is not common and I have so far found this on one computer only. It can be reproduced but I do not have the develop environment on that computer. The error appears when calling SyncLock/lock on an object.

What could create this kind of error?

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object obj)
```

Comment: I assume you are trying to lock on obj? why not create a new instance of obj somewhere in the start and do a lock(obj){...}

Comment: that is intriguing; any more context on what the object is that you're using for the lock token?

Comment: Throw away the machine.  Spending the time to try to diagnose *that* isn't worth it.

Comment: The lock is on a normal new object:

    Private LockWaitQueue As New Object


Lock is called through:

    SyncLock LockWaitQueue

Comment: Does the exception occur at a specific time such as when a thread or process is starting or stopping?

Comment: Yes, it occurs right after starting a process.